# Smarty Undefiend Variable As Array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, whmcs

I have a smarty application that was written about 1 year ago ,  now i migrated to Smarty v3 and i've got some errors in my code that i dont have any clue how to fix them. here i will list them , thanks

1-Cannot use object of type Smarty_Undefined_Variable as array

```
$this->_tpl_vars['cart']['domains'] = array();
```

i was able to set variable like this but now i'm getting error with this code , i read the Smarty document and it said : for making variables i should use this code :

```
$template->assign('myNewVariable', 'myNewValue');
```

the problem is that i want to add an array in variable and its nested like the code i have shown above and i need something like this  as array :

```
 $template->assign('cart[domains]', 'myNewValue');
```

or maybe :

```
$test= $template->assign('cart', array);
$domain=$test->assign('domains',array);
```

both of them should be assigned as array.

Comment: That last bit of code is confusing with the reuse of `$test` like that, first craft your array such as `$var = array('foo','bar');` then assign it using `$smarty->assign('name',$var);` or `$smarty->assign('name',array('foo','bar'));`

Comment: thanks i will test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to an array to a variable, you can do like this

```
$arr['domain']=YourNewValue;
$template->assign('cart', $arr);
```

Simple as that.